# Python - Record on loop, stop recording when silent

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying to write a Python script that will record 5-second segments of speech on a loop for as long as the user is speaking, and will stop after three wave files of pure silence. How would I go about this?

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                channels = CHANNELS,
                rate = RATE,
                input = True,
                frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for j in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://github.com/rhasspy/rhasspy-silence library

Here is a little code for u (not mine, but it works.):

```
from rhasspysilence import WebRtcVadRecorder,VoiceCommand, VoiceCommandResult
import threading
import dataclasses
import typing
from queue import Queue
import json
import io
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shlex
import time
import wave
import sys
import subprocess
import pyaudio
pa =pyaudio.PyAudio()
#you can change the options (these are default settings)
vad_mode = 3
sample_rate = 16000
min_seconds= 1
max_seconds = 30
speech_seconds = 0.3
silence_seconds = 0.5
before_seconds = 0.2
chunk_size= 960
skip_seconds = 0
audio_source = None
channels =1
def SpeechToText():
    recorder = WebRtcVadRecorder(vad_mode=vad_mode,)
    recorder.start()
    # file directory
    wav_sink = 'wavs/'
    wav_dir = None
    # file name
    wav_filename = 'tester'
    if wav_sink:
        wav_sink_path = Path(wav_sink)
        if wav_sink_path.is_dir():
            # Directory to write WAV files
            wav_dir = wav_sink_path
        else:
            # Single WAV file to write
            wav_sink = open(wav_sink, "wb")
    voice_command: typing.Optional[VoiceCommand] = None
    audio_source = pa.open(rate=sample_rate,format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=channels,input=True,frames_per_buffer=chunk_size)
    audio_source.start_stream()
    print("Ready", file=sys.stderr)
    def buffer_to_wav(buffer: bytes) -> bytes:
        """Wraps a buffer of raw audio data in a WAV"""
        rate = int(sample_rate)
        width = int(2)
        channels = int(1)
 
        with io.BytesIO() as wav_buffer:
            wav_file: wave.Wave_write = wave.open(wav_buffer, mode="wb")
            with wav_file:
                wav_file.setframerate(rate)
                wav_file.setsampwidth(width)
                wav_file.setnchannels(channels)
                wav_file.writeframesraw(buffer)
 
            return wav_buffer.getvalue()
    try:
        chunk = audio_source.read(chunk_size)
        while chunk:
 
            # Look for speech/silence
            voice_command = recorder.process_chunk(chunk)
 
            if voice_command:
                is_timeout = voice_command.result == VoiceCommandResult.FAILURE
                # Reset
                audio_data = recorder.stop()
                if wav_dir:
                    # Write WAV to directory
                    wav_path = (wav_dir / time.strftime(wav_filename)).with_suffix(
                        ".wav"
                    )
                    wav_bytes = buffer_to_wav(audio_data)
                    wav_path.write_bytes(wav_bytes)
                    print(wav_path)
                    print('file saved')
                    break
                elif wav_sink:
                    # Write to WAV file
                    wav_bytes = core.buffer_to_wav(audio_data)
                    wav_sink.write(wav_bytes)
            # Next audio chunk
            chunk = audio_source.read(chunk_size)
 
    finally:
        try:
            audio_source.close_stream()
        except Exception:
            pass
#execute command
SpeechToText()
```